# How to implement a backup for AWS Timestream table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-timestream

I am trying to figure out which is the best approach to build backups of a database or a table in Amazon timestream.

In the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/disaster-recovery-resiliency.html) page you can read this:

> While Amazon Timestream is multi-AZ, it does not support backups to other AWS Availability Zones or Regions. However, you can write your own application using the Timestream SDK to query data and save it to the destination of your choice.

Therefore, AWS does not help me too much in this case, since querying hourly or daily with scheduled queries and storing all the data in another table does not seem to me a very optimal option.

Has anyone faced the same problem and approached it differently? Perhaps using other AWS services and optimizing the costs generated?

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Since then AWS has released an integration with AWS Backup: [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/timestream-backup.html), [2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/backups-how-it-works.html). There is also a 3rd party CLI tool called [Timestream travel](https://github.com/mgjules/timestream-travel)